# Using GKE ingress with https load balancer and IAP/security policy enabled

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have an application that uses GKE Ingress (master version 1.10.6-gke.2)  for a load balancer.  Recently GKE started supporting declaring IAP support via `BackendConfig`.  I followed the documentation at [1] and [2].  However, now, GKE seems to hang while creating my Ingress.

Below is the yaml for my service, ingress and backendconfig.

`kubectl -n randall-test-1 get svc,ing,backendconfig -o yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    annotations:
      beta.cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"default": "airflow-backend-config"}'
      service.alpha.kubernetes.io/app-protocols: '{"web":"HTTPS"}'
    creationTimestamp: 2018-09-10T19:23:13Z
    name: airflow
    namespace: randall-test-1
    resourceVersion: "2155724"
    selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/randall-test-1/services/airflow
    uid: X-X-X-X-X
  spec:
    clusterIP: X.X.X.X
    externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
    ports:
    - name: web
      nodePort: 30099
      port: 8080
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: web
    selector:
      app: airflow
    sessionAffinity: None
    type: NodePort
  status:
    loadBalancer: {}
- apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
  kind: Ingress
  metadata:
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
    creationTimestamp: 2018-09-10T19:23:13Z
    generation: 1
    name: airflow
    namespace: randall-test-1
    resourceVersion: "2155721"
    selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/randall-test-1/ingresses/airflow
    uid: X-X-X-X-X
  spec:
    backend:
      serviceName: airflow
      servicePort: 8080
    tls:
    - secretName: tls
  status:
    loadBalancer: {}
- apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1beta1
  kind: BackendConfig
  metadata:
    clusterName: ""
    creationTimestamp: 2018-09-10T19:23:13Z
    generation: 1
    name: airflow-backend-config
    namespace: randall-test-1
    resourceVersion: "2155728"
    selfLink: /apis/cloud.google.com/v1beta1/namespaces/randall-test-1/backendconfigs/airflow-backend-config
    uid: X-X-X-X-X
  spec:
    iap:
      enabled: true
      oauthclientCredentials:
        secretName: oauth2
kind: List
metadata:
  resourceVersion: ""
  selfLink: ""
```

The hang gives me no insight.

```
cluster@master0:~/kube-config$ kubectl -n randall-test-1 describe ing
Name:             airflow
Namespace:        randall-test-1
Address:
Default backend:  airflow:8080 (X.X.X.X:8080)
TLS:
  tls terminates
Rules:
  Host  Path  Backends
  ----  ----  --------
  *     *     airflow:8080 (X.X.X.X:8080)
Annotations:
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age   From                     Message
  ----    ------  ----  ----                     -------
  Normal  ADD     6m    loadbalancer-controller  randall-test-1/airflow
```

However, in GKE console, I just get `Creating ingress` as a status for > 20 mins with no resolution.  I also check my `Load Balancers` in console and see nothing.

Any ideas what is happening or what else I can check?

I also tried to do this with just `securityPolicy` which is supposed to link the Load Balancer with a Cloud Armor policy.   This also doesn't work with a similar hang.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enabling-kubernetes-howto

[2] https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/backendconfig

NOTE: cross posted at https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/issues/469

Comment: did you check the logs for kube-controller-manager and kube-apiserver in your active k8s master.  Some auth or api to GCP might be failing.

Answer (score 0):

We've been getting a few similar cases in the past few days. There seems to be something wrong with permissions of the default GKE service account.

Can you try to add the following [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/custom-roles-permissions-support) to it:

- clientauthconfig.clients.update
- clientauthconfig.clients.get